# save NFT addresses in smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

im sure this has been done alot before, however

is it possible to when minting NFTs save all those nft addresses in that contract so in my program i can get all those addresses.
this is for the purpose of checking if the user has any of those addresses in thier account by getting the minted nft addresses and then looping through if they have any of those in thier account.

If this isnt possible what is the best way to check if the user has an nft they need.

Comment: Do you want the addresses of all created NFTs to be registered in a special smart contract, which will actually keep a register of all issued NFTs?

Comment: are you talking about this https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721Enumerable?

Comment: @MadJackal yep exactly